# Import a C++ DLL into C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I try to implement a C++ DLL into my C# project. I've given the following header file:

```
#ifdef EBEXPORT
const long EBDECL
#else
const long EBDECL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

const long EBCALL __stdcall


#if defined (__cplusplus)
extern "C" 
{
#endif

EBDECL long EBCALL EbInitTcp(long nUnit, const char* pIP, long nIPSize);

#if defined (__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

This is my code which I use to implement the DLL in C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NoName
{
    class DLLImport
    {
        [DllImport("C:/lib/host.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern long EbInitTcp(long nUnit, string pIP, long nIPSize);

        public void Init()
        {
            string ip = "192.168.0.1";
            EbInitTcp(1, ip, ip.Length));
        }

    }
}
```

If I execute the code I get a *PInvokeStackImbalance* exception.
Could you please help me?

Comment: `int EbInitTcp(int nUnit, string pIP, int nIPSize)`.

Comment: The calling convention is usually defined with a `#define`, i.e. `#define EBCALL __stdcall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imbalance can be caused by a mismatch calling convention (`cdecl` vs. `stdcall`) or mismatch function arguments, both in size and type.

The C++ calling convention definition is little unusual, it is normally defined with a `#define`.

```
#ifdef EBEXPORT
  #define EBDECL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define EBDECL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define EBCALL __stdcall

#if defined (__cplusplus)
extern "C" 
{
#endif

EBDECL const long EBCALL EbInitTcp(long nUnit, const char* pIP, long nIPSize);

#if defined (__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

On the C# side;

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NoName
{
    class DLLImport
    {
        [DllImport("C:/lib/host.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern long EbInitTcp(int nUnit, string pIP, int nIPSize);

        public void Init()
        {
            string ip = "192.168.0.1";
            EbInitTcp(1, ip, ip.Length));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify your calling convention; beware that `extern "C"` defaults to [`CallingConvention.Cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=netcore-3.1). This error is usually caused by wrong calling convention.

Also beware that C#'s `long` and C++'s `long` may be different.

It looks like you're trying to specify `__stdcall`, but it's a syntax error. In any case make sure your calling conventions are synchronized.

Comment: The c++ header file is given, so I can't change that.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile; please *verify* positively that the calling conventions are what you think they are.

Comment: I can compile the code without errors; I also had verified the calling conventions.

Comment: "extern "C" defaults to CallingConvention.Cdecl"  Not so much.  `extern "C"` makes no difference, all global functions will default to the calling convention [specified on the compiler command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gd-gr-gv-gz-calling-convention?view=vs-2019).